# git remote is not there after repo is cloned again

Tags: git, gitlab, fork, git-remote

I have tried to make a fork of a github repo in an internal gitlab server by making an empty repo on GitLab, cloning it, and doing

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo
git pull upstream master
git push origin main
```

This worked and I have the files and history of the master branch of the github repo.  `git branch -r` now shows `origin/main` and `upstream/master`.
However, when I clone the repository for a second time there is no `upstream/master` shown by `git branch -r`.

If I need to pull new commits from `upstream/master` and then apply them to my repo, do I just need to re-add the remote, pull from it, and then rebase my changes? Is there any way to have the remotes included when I clone the repo?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect this to work automagically? `git remote add` adds a remote only to the current local repository. "*…do I just need to re-add the remote, pull from it, and then rebase my changes?"* Yes. "*Is there any way to have the remotes included when I clone the repo?*" No. Write a script, commit and push it; run after any clone — that's the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am surprised there is not a neat way to "commit" the new config of the repo so that all that is required to have the same environment is a `git clone`.

Comment: These is a security measure. A cloned repository must not force any local configuration and especially must not run any commands. Only the object database (commits, trees, blobs) and references (branches and tags) are cloned. Everything else is up to the local user. Hooks and scripts to set up config could be (and often are) copied to the working dir, committed and pushed. But the local user is free to ignore them. Security!